# filter convolution reflection boundary

Tags: c++, reflection, convolution, boundary

i got big problem how to set the boundarys when i make convolution. We got this part of code, i already implemented the zero padding, but now i have to reflect the pixel values to the boundary.

```
bool ConvolutionFilter::Execute()
{
// First, create a valid output image.
// This fails, if no valid input image is available.
if( !CreateOutputImage() )
{
    return false;
}
// Check if convolution kernel is set.
if( m_Kernel == NULL )
{
    std::cout << "Error: No convolution kernel set!" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

/* Execute the convolution filter. */



/*
 * Hier sind schonmal ein paar Konstanten definiert, die Sie brauchen.
 * Kommentieren Sie den Code aus, wenn Sie diese benutzen.
 */

const int kernelHalfSizeX = m_Kernel->GetHalfSizeX();
const int kernelHalfSizeY = m_Kernel->GetHalfSizeY();
//const int kernelSizeX     = m_Kernel->GetSizeX();
const int imageSizeX = static_cast<int>(m_InputImage->GetSizeX());
const int imageSizeY = static_cast<int>(m_InputImage->GetSizeY());
int conv, value;
/*
 * TODO: Aufgabe 3: Implementieren Sie die Faltung des Eingabe-Bildes m_InputImage
 * mit der Filtermaske m_Kernel und schreiben sie das Ergebnis in das Ausgabe-Bild
 * m_OutputImage.
 * Die Faltung ist gegeben als:
 * f_out(x,y)=sum from{j=-hY} to{hY} sum from{i=-hX} to{hX} f(x+i,y+j) * g(i,j)
 *
 * Aufgabe 3b: Verwenden Sie dabei 0-Randbedingungen, d.h. wenn (x+i,y+j) ausserhalb des Bildbereiches
 * liegen, ist f(x+i,y+j) * g(i,j) = 0.
 *
 * Sie koennen mit m_Kernel->GetCoefficient(i,j) auf die Werte der Filtermaske zugreifen.
 * Lesen Sie die Kommentare in der Klasse ConvolutionKernel fÃ¼r Details!
 *
 * Beachten Sie, dass i und j auch negative Werte annehmen, und deshalb nicht unsigned sein
 * koennen. Evtl. muessen Sie (abhaengig vom Compiler) das Ergebnis von m_InputImage->GetSizeX()
 * bzw. m_InputImage->GetSizeY() zunaechst von unsigned int nach signed int konvertieren, um
 * Warnings bei einem Vergleich mit vorzeichenbehafteten Werten zu vermeiden, oder verwenden Sie
 * die oben definierten Konstanten imageSizeX, imageSizeY.
 */

/*
 * TODO: Aufgabe 3c: Veraendern Sie ihren Code aus Aufg 3b so, dass reflektierende Randbedingungen
 * verwendet werden (siehe Aufgabenblatt).
 * ACHTUNG: Kommentieren sie den Code aus Aufg 3b nur aus, und loeschen Sie diesen nicht!
 *
 */
for(int x = 0; x<=imageSizeX; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y<=imageSizeY; y++)
    {
        conv = 0;
        for(int j = -kernelHalfSizeY; j<=kernelHalfSizeY; j++)
        {
            for(int i = -kernelHalfSizeX; i<=kernelHalfSizeX; i++)
            {
                if(x+i>0 || x+i<imageSizeX || y+j>0 || y+j<imageSizeY) {
                 value = m_InputImage->GetPixel(x+i,y+j);
                }
                 else
                 {

                    value = m_InputImage->GetPixel();
                    //value = 0; //Zero-Padding
                 }
                    conv  += value*m_Kernel->GetCoefficient(i,j);
            }
        }
        printf("conv: %d\n", conv);
        m_OutputImage->SetPixel(x,y,conv);
    }
}


return true;
}
```

So how i can get the pixel values for different mask sizes to reflect them to the boundary out of the image?

Answer (score -2):

```
int xi = x + i;

if ( xi < 0 ) xi = - xi;
else if ( xi > imageSizeX ) xi = imageSizeX - xi;

int yj = y + j;

... same ...

value = m_InputImage->GetPixel(xi,yj);
```

I don't think this requires explanation…

Comment: thanks so this is for reflecting the values to the outer boundarys?

Comment: @user1860010 If the x/y coordinates go outside imageSizeX/Y, then this just reflects them by subtracting the coordinate from the boundary. It doesn't handle the case of the filter kernel being larger than the image, which requires double reflection. You can implement that using the modulo `%` operator if it's necessary.

Comment: oh ok, the filter kernel should not be larger than the image. So this was the task once a zero padding and then the reflection. thanks

Comment: i calculate the first pixel with calculator and the new pixel value should be 162 with reflection and the output of my code says 76 which should be wrong so is the convolution part wrong or?

Comment: @user1860010 How am I supposed to know? Note that this code doesn't duplicate the pixels at the edges. If the first two pixels are {0, 1, …} then the filter will see {… 1, 0, 1, …} not {… 1, 0, 0, 1, … }. To try the other way, use `xi = - xi + 1` and adjust the other cases similarly.